# Angular 2 Karma test cancel timeout

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have the functions below. I want to test that the timeout is cancelled correctly.

The scenario is i have a menu that opens when a button is clicked, this calls the start timer. The timer will close the menu after x seconds. However if the menu is closed before the timeout, i want to cancel it.

The problem is Karama halts until the timeout happens. I want to click the cancel button straight after but the view isn't updated until after the timeout which, then triggers the whenStable() function.

```
  private setReleaseTimeout() {
    this.releaseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if (this.showReleaseOptions) {
        this.showReleaseOptionsSubject.next(false);
      }
    }.bind(this), this.configService.get('extendOptionsTimeout'));
  }
  private cancelReleaseTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(this.releaseTimeout);
  }
```

I test with:

```
it('Buttons should revert after clicking cancel', (done)  => {
  let buttons = getButtons()

  buttons[0].click(); // release button
  done();
  // get the buttons that are showing
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Cheers
D

P.S. I have tried all sorts of combinations of done(), sync, fakeAsync but can't quite achieve it.

Comment: Nobody has come across this issue?